# How to declare a pointer to a character array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do I declare a pointer to a character array in C?

Comment: I'm tempted to say something snarky like "Read the assigned chapter"... in any event, you need more information: language? overall objective? context? This doesn't seem to meet the bar of expectation of questions on this site.

Comment: Do you really want a pointer to an array?  Or a pointer to the first element of an array?  Do you know about [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)?

Comment: To expand a bit on Carl's point: a pointer to an array is possible, but rarely (oh, so *very* rarely) needed or wanted. Most of the time, you want a pointer to (often const) char.

Comment: Thanks for answering @CarlNorum , the funny part is I was expecting the respective page from cplusplus.com, but this outranked it, which is good because know I know about cdecl!

Comment: @JerryCoffin "~rarely (oh, so very rarely) needed or wanted" are you talking in the C++ application or C? I thought `int main (int argc, char** argv)` is common in the C (`char** argv` is an example of the pointer to the array).

Comment: @CloudCho: that's a pointer to a pointer, which happens to refer to the initial element of an array--but it still doesn't have type "pointer to array".

Comment: The pointer isn't the array of character, for example, `argv[0] = "main.cpp"` in C language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess I'll give this answer in parts:

1. Here's a pointer to an array of `char`s (I assumed a 10-element array):

   ```
   char (*x)[10];
   ```

   Let's break it down from the basics:

   ```
   x
   ```

   is a pointer:

   ```
   *x
   ```

   to an array:

   ```
   (*x)[10]
   ```

   of `char`s:

   ```
   char (*x)[10]
   ```
2. However, most of the time you don't really want a pointer to an array, you want a pointer to the first element of an array.  In that case:

   ```
   char a[10];
   char *x = a;
   char *y = &a[0];
   ```

   Either `x` or `y` are what you're looking for, and are equivalent.
3. Tip:  Learn about [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.org) to make these problems easier on yourself.

Comment: @Carl I think you've missed some asterisks in item 2

Comment: Yup - most definitely.  Thanks, @sidyll!  If you see me do that in the future, feel free to edit them in yourself - it seems you have plenty of rep to do so.

Comment: Well, I just didn't want to break the integrity of the answer from a user for whom I have great respect!

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it as `extern char (*p)[];`, but it's an *incomplete type*. This is of course because C has no "array" type generically that is a complete type; only arrays of a specific size are complete types.

The following works:

```
extern char (*p)[];

char arr[20];

char (*p)[20] = &arr;  // complete type now: p points to an array of 20 chars
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest...

Declaration is:
`char* array;`

And then definition is:
`array = "James Bond";`

To print out:
`printf ("%s \n", array);`

Some programmers probably mention the above code isn't memory safe or the definition is actually re assignment, so

`char* array = "James Bond";`

would be a general practice.