# How to declare a pointer to : array of void pointers? in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm little bit confused about how to declare a pointer to array or void*.

let say :

```
void* myarr[20];
```

how to declare a pointer to "myarr?"

Comment: Related, if not the same (in the sense of how to declare a pointer to an array): http://stackoverflow.com/q/9779450/694576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to void.

It is simply to do if you will use the following general approach. Let's assume that you have an array of some type `T`

```
T myarr[20];
```

then the definition of the pointer to the first element of the array will look like

```
T *ptr = myarr;
```

Now all what you need is substitute `T` for you particulat type and you will get

```
void * myarr[20];

void * *ptr = myarr;
```

If you mean indeed a pointer to the array then approach is the following

```
T myarr[20];
T ( *ptr )[20] = &myarr;
```

Or if to substitute `T` for `void *` you will get

```
void * myarr[20];
void * ( *ptr )[20] = &myarr;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef void *myarr_t[20];
myarr_t *ptr_to_myarr;
```

Comment: why you chooe typdef?

Comment: Because declaring a "pointer to an array of 20 void pointers" directly would result in complicated syntax. When I use the typedef, it means I get the type of `myarr` and put it as `myarr_t`, afterwards I can just say "give me a pointer to type of myarr".

Answer (score 1):

```
void* (*myarr_ptr)[20] = myarr_ptr;
```

here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int* myarr[20];
    int * (*myarr_ptr)[20] = myarr;
    printf("%p %p\n", myarr, *myarr_ptr);

    return 0;
}

$ ./a.out 
0x7fff8bd39dd0 0x7fff8bd39dd0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void** ptrToArrary = myarr_t; //pointing to base address of array.
```

Comment: why not void* prtToArray = myarr_t; ?

Comment: To hold address of normal variable you need pointer, to hold address of pointer you need pointer to pointer.

Comment: So what i wrote to you (void* prtToArray = myarr_t;) it illegal?

Comment: name of array represents pointer to element zero. `arr[10]` then `arr` is `arr = &arr[0]`

Comment: @user3729959 It would have been legal if you write `void prtToArray = myarr_t[0];`

Comment: `ptrToArrary` is not a pointer to a fixed size array (as per the OP's question), but a pointer to the arrays 1st element only: -1